# "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: pip

when trying to install *flask-mysql* i get the following error msg:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/2n/pv5q13p10dz6rg8qlh3vhxv00000gn/T/pip-build-bh92ufyu/MySQL-python

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem when install `matplotlib` and following command workd:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools

pip install ez_setup
```

Ref [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/python-pip-install-gives-command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-c)

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me:

```
easy_install distribute
pip install --upgrade distribute
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing python-dev, libpython-dev, libevent-dev and try again...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem when trying to run PostgreSQL in a Alpine Docker container.
Apparently some base libraries are not included in the Alpine image for `psycopg2` to work properly and therefore need to be installed separately on the image. For me the problem was resolved by adding the following line to my `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN apk update && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev
```