# pip install error tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

am trying to install tensorflow but am getting this following error, i have updated the setup tools also,
    command: pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow

```
error:
writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\absl_py.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\absl_py.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
'c:\\users\\user\\downloads\\python-3.5.2-embed-
amd64\\python35.zip\\lib2to3\\Grammar.txt'
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-hhz6jia9\absl-py\
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896424/tensorflow-not-found-in-pip.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embedded Python 3.5 "python setup.py egg\_info" failed with error code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962765/embedded-python-3-5-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1)

Comment: This is [a bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue24960) in lib2to3. Upgrade your Python to 3.5.4.