# setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 when trying to install beautifulsoup

Tags: python, terminal, beautifulsoup

Ive been googling for hours to no luck.

Whenever I try to pip install beautiful soup in terminal, i get the following error:

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/h4/0vpghp6j7xbgzctcbm50btf00000gn/T/pip-install-jd0tuia4/beautifulsoup/

I tried everything suggested here to no luck. ["python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32068325/python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1)

Can anybody help me figure out whats going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the full error message in your question. If you are starting a new project, it might be better to install `beautifulsoup4`, which supports Python 3, instead of the legacy `beautifulsoup`.

Comment: try `pip install bs4`

Answer (score 4):

for python 2 use

```
pip install beautifulsoup
```

and for python3

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

It is recommended to use `beautifulsoup4` for new projects as `beautifulsoup3` is no longer being developed.