# error: package directory 'PSM' does not exist push failure

Tags: python, heroku, flask, package

Getting this error when attempting to push my flask app to heroku for the first time:

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> Installing python-3.6.6
-----> Installing pip
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
   Obtaining file:///tmp/build_4ef7a6c864d09dbc04794509b4531098 (from -r /tmp/build_4ef7a6c864d09dbc04794509b4531098/requirements.txt (line 1))
       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
       running egg_info
       writing PSM.egg-info/PKG-INFO
       writing dependency_links to PSM.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
       writing requirements to PSM.egg-info/requires.txt
       writing top-level names to PSM.egg-info/top_level.txt
       error: package directory 'PSM' does not exist

       ----------------------------------------
   Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/build_4ef7a6c864d09dbc04794509b4531098/
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

Here is my file structure:

```
PSM/
    .vscode/
    flask_session/
    psm/(all python, JS, html etc. in here)
    PSM.egg-info/
    procfile
    requirements.txt
    setup.py
```

And my setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
   name='PSM',
    packages=['psm'],
include_package_data=True,
install_requires=[
    'flask',
],
)
```

Even when I change the names of the folders (PSM & psm) and the setup.py and remake the egg info it still says:

```
error: package directory 'PSM' does not exist
```

I have already upgraded setup tools as suggested here and installed ez setup as suggested in these links respectively:

[Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/3884)

[“python setup.py egg_info” failed with error code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32068325/python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1)

Edit 1: Going to start reading through setup tools documentation. Hopefully I can find an answer in there.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, I have made a new project. First, I followed the flask installation instructions:

[flask installation setup](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/installation/#installation)

I then followed the quickstart guide:

[flask quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/)

And finally, I converted it to a large application so it is a package.

[flask larger application](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/packages/)

Then, I copied my subdirectory with my application name: i.e.

```
PSM/
.vscode/
flask_session/
psm/(all python, JS, html etc. in here)<----COPY THIS
PSM.egg-info/
procfile
requirements.txt
setup.py
```

into here

```
PSM2/
.vscode/
flask_session/
psm2/<--- Replaced this folder with old folder
PSM2.egg-info/
procfile
requirements.txt
setup.py
```

I'm not sure what was wrong with the original project, but hopefully this may help someone if they run into the same problem!